# ActiveMQ throwing org.apache.activemq.ra.LocalAndXATransaction

Tags: activemq-classic, weblogic11g

I have ActiveMQ cluster(Horizontal)  setup deployed on Weblogic Server, using GFS for persistent store with Master/Slave setup, it works well with only Master Node running but when I start Slave node the Master Node start throwing following exceptions in weblogic managed server .out logs.. I have take this issue up with oracle as well following is there response: 
**Oracle Support**

1) No sure why its running fine master node and facing issue with slave node. 
 Since the error getting triggered from the MQ code, I cannot comment much on the same. Please let me know whether you checked with your application team. 
 What's their comment regarding the exception reported? Please keep me posted .

Thank you.

2) I have gone through the Server log provided on this Service request and verified the case.

As per the log, the EJB exception caused due to the Null pointer exception, which getting triggered from the MQ code. Suggest you to check with the application regarding the same

Regards, 
Vaisakh.S
App Development Team

Looks like it’s this bit of code that is causing the null pointer. I’ve tracked down the full stack trace which indicates the line highlighted below, this.connection must be null. This is all ActiveMQ internals though, nothing custom with application.

code see in comment

Following logs are taken from weblogic managed .out logs 
see comment as stackoverflow did't allowing

Comment: EJB Exception: : javax.transaction.TransactionRolledbackException: EJB Exception: : javax.transaction.SystemException: start() failed on resource 'org.apache.activemq.ra.LocalAndXATransaction': XAER_RMERR : A resource manager error has occured in the transaction branch 
 javax.transaction.xa.XAException: Unexpected Exception for XAResource 'org.apache.activemq.ra.LocalAndXATransaction':nulljava.lang.NullPointerException 
 at org.apache.activemq.TransactionContext.setXid(TransactionContext.java:676) 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Code: private void setXid(Xid xid) throws XAException { 

 try { 
 this.connection.checkClosedOrFailed(); 
 this.connection.ensureConnectionInfoSent(); 
 } catch (JMSException e) { 
 disassociate(); 
 throw toXAException(e); 
 }